# How to execute IF query in MYSQL with python?

Tags: python, mysql

Am struggling with executing IF query of MYSQL in python. My Query works fine in MYSQL Workbench but not able to execute via python.There is no problem in establishing connection though.
Coming to Scenario I Have a table named 'Report' in database 'scorecard' where i have 3 columns. Column names are 'Student_ID','Subject' and 'Mark'. to get a 'Result' column with pass or fail status i executed following IF query in MYSQL which works fine there.

```
    USE scorecard;
    SELECT Mark,
    IF(Mark>=55,"PASS","FAIL")
    AS Result
    FROM Report;
```

But when executing this code in python i wrote following code after establishing connection with database,but not working.

```
    sql1="Select Mark ,IF(Mark>=55,"PASS","FAIL") AS Result FROM Report"
    mycursor.execute(sql1)
    mydb.commit()
```

Please help me how to write such big queries of MYSQL in python to get executed
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Since you're in the middle of a double-quoted, string, try using single quotes for the `'PASS','FAIL'` part. Also you missed the comma between `Mark` and `IF`.

Comment: tried but not working..

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: Why do you commit after the select and where do you read the actual results?

Comment: The code you've posted would give a syntax error on `sql1="Select Mark ,IF(Mark>=55,"PASS","FAIL") AS Result FROM Report"` before you even got to trying to execute it. Please post a [mre] and give full details of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because you can't put simply double quotes in a double quoted string

So you can make **single quotes** ot of it

```
sql1="Select Mark ,IF(Mark>=55,'PASS','FAIL') AS Result FROM Report"
mycursor.execute(sql1)
records = mycursor.fetchall()
mydb.commit()
```

Or you **escape** the double Quotes

```
sql1="Select Mark ,IF(Mark>=55,\"PASS\",\"FAIL\") AS Result FROM Report"
mycursor.execute(sql1)
records = mycursor.fetchall()
mydb.commit()
```

And last there is the option with **triple quotes**

```
sql1="""Select Mark ,IF(Mark>=55,"PASS","FAIL") AS Result FROM Report"""
mycursor.execute(sql1)
records = mycursor.fetchall()
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: One more doubt regarding this, when i try to get records of passed student by following query " SELECT * FROM Report WHERE Result='PASS' " its showing following error "mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found". Does the result column that we get by IF function doesnt stay there. How to make it a permanent column? In excel we  can assign a formula to a column, like that is it possible in MYSQL? Please help

Comment: Bedore you make another query you must fetch the data before you can run another query, that us why i added records = mycursor.fetchall() so the reslut of your select is read and stored in the variable records